# Japnese TTS on android

Tags: android

I have to develop an android app for Japan which has to use Text to Speech engine (Japnese TTS). When an android phone is sold in Japnese market are the users provided with a default Text to Speech engine in their language ?

I know they can buy a TTS engine from market and programatically I have to place checks of TTS engine existence 
but I need to know if I can expect the engine installed by default on MOST OF THE PHONES I have to make a feasibility decision based on this

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used three different Android phones from NTT Docomo, and they all had both English and Japanese TTS installed by default. The few Androids on AU I saw came with it also. I don't know for sure about SoftBank, but I'd wager they are the same.

For the record, I had an HT-03A(HTC Magic), Galaxy S, and Galaxy S2 while living there.

Comment: Thanks, thumbs up for your answer. What does AU stands for ?

Comment: It's the name of one the wireless companies there. AU, or sometimes AU.kddi, but no idea what it stands for. The three I named above are the big three in Japan, and cover at least 90% of the market, probably 95% or more.

Comment: Sure , I'd mark your answer as correct if no one else could provide better info than yours. Thanks